# How to show "Alternative text" of image fields in a custom content type?

Tags: theming, entities, 8

I created a custom content type that its name is **News** and has an image field with **news_image** machanic name and I added an `alternative text` to it from administration page,
now I want to print that alternative text when the node content type twig template rendered.
what I want to achieve finally is schematically something like below:

```
<img src="#" title="#" alt="Alternative text">
```

> It seems this problem can be traced back to custom content type only
>   because alternative text can be printed without any problem in default content type like article.

Comment: It already does this by default. [ImageFormatter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!image!src!Plugin!Field!FieldFormatter!ImageFormatter.php/function/ImageFormatter%3A%3AviewElements/8.2.x) (wrong link sorry).

Comment: I tried with simplytest.me and this is what I did - http://imgur.com/GinCNnO (currently at https://rr9hd.ply.st, but that site goes away).

Comment: Maybe there is something else custom with the content type, node template, entity/node render, or field rendering.

Comment: what is your method to render your field in node twig file? did you render with {{ content.news_image}} ?

Comment: No, I use this method `<img src="{{ file_url(node.field_news_image.entity.fileuri) }}" >`

Comment: @MojtabaReyhani you forgot mention me in your comment reply and I didn't inform about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get "alt" property with `node.FIELD_MACHINE_NAME.alt` (and for image title as the same ), So your answer is

```
<img src="{{ file_url(node.field_news_image.entity.fileuri) }}" alt="{{ node.field_news_image.alt }}" >
```

Comment: @MojtabaReyhani you're welcome :)